# How do I disable a screen overlay

Tags: samsung, popup, overlay

I recently purchased a Samsung S7.  I placed it on charge last night and this morning when I went to check my messages I keep getting a popup/overlay displaying a playboy style icon with a close box and info box.  I just hit back up on the phone but it keeps re appearing.

Can anyone help, it's driving me mad.

Thanks in advance.

Richard

Answer (score 0):

Try going in settings - apps - wrench icon - draw over other apps - deselect the app you think is showing the overlay.
I'd recommend you to uninstall the app after.

Comment: I have no clue which app it is :(

Comment: Can you list some apps you installed yourself? Or disable all overlays on apps you don't need overlays with.

Comment: Or possibly send a screenshot of how the overlay looks like?

Comment: How do I send the screenshot on here?